# c# htmlagility pack, Page not Found

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to load the page source of following website using Htmlagility C#, it always return "Page Not Found" but when i open it in normal browser (chrome) its displaying all the contents.

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc = web.Load("http://www.alfatah.pk/");
```

Comment: Most likely you are trying to (potentially illegally) scrape a site that have some protections against it. It should be very easily to confirm that by using Fiddler and comparing requests. It may be good idea to start learning web scraping from your own site that does not  have any such protections.

Comment: is there any way to scrape this site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting a 404 as well with your code. Somehow they are aware that we are no human beings but web robots!

This works for me:

```
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        web.UserAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0";

        web.PreRequest += (request) =>
        {
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "de-DE");
            return true;
        };
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

        doc = web.Load("http://www.alfatah.pk/");
```

Comment: with your code  i'm getting this exception "Additional information: The 'Accept' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method."

Comment: Same for AcceptLanguage

Comment: request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "de-DE");

Comment: i'm sorry! but i'm getting same exception "The 'Accept' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method."

Comment: As I said it's working fine on my side. I recommend you to create a new question for this issue as it's unrelated to the current one. I have some code that might do the trick.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462643/c-sharp-htmlagility-getting-exception-when-i-add-header-in-following-code

Comment: here is new question,