# C# htmlagility, getting exception when i add header in following code

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm getting exception when i run this code 
Exception "header must be modified using the appropriate property or method."

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        web.UserAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
         AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36";
        web.PreRequest += (request) =>
        {
            request.Headers.Add("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "de-DE");
            return true;
        };
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new 
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

        doc = web.Load("http://www.alfatah.pk/");
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.accept

Comment: Just supposing that it is a bug in the library: you could use other tools like HttpClient, HttpWebRequest or WebClient to download the content and use HtmlAgilityPack from string or stream source...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in https://dotnetfiddle.net/AQbs3v :

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.alfatah.pk/");
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit / 537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 70.0.3538.77 Safari / 537.36";
 request.Accept= "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        //request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "de-DE");

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(request.GetResponse()))
        {
            HttpStatusCode code = response.StatusCode;
            if (code == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
                    htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
                    htmlDoc.Load(sr);
                    Console.Write(htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerText);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: PS, do you have the latest version of HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: i think you have installed something else, that i haven't

Comment: These are the usings:  using System.Net; using HtmlAgilityPack; Do you have the latest version of Visual Studio? Whats the error you're getting?

Comment: i have 2015vs and latest version of htmlagility.. you can try your code here https://dotnetfiddle.net/AQbs3v

Comment: I did and it works after making another modification, see above